# How to align button with dropdown inline with other link anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

> `I want the drop-down menu to be aligned properly not to the left side of the screen. I want it responsive

```css
.top-section{
   padding-top: 2rem;
}
.btn-search{
   background-color: #EEEFEE;
   border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.fa-search{
   color: #8E8F8F;
}
.form-control{
   border-radius: 0px !important;
}
.link-end{
   text-align: end;
   display: flex;
    justify-content: end;
    align-items: baseline;
}
.first-link{
   margin-right: 2rem;
}
@media (max-width:991px) {
   .link-end{
      padding-top: 2rem;
   }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta charset="UTF-8">
   <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <!-- jQuery library -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Popper JS -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
   <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
   <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
   <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f1e10fbba5.js"></script> 
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
   <title>Print-Shop Contact</title>
</head>
<body>
   <div class="top-section">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
               <div class="input-group">
                  <input type="text" class="form-control">
                  <div class="input-group-append">
                    <button class="btn btn-search" type="button">
                      <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>
           <!--Empty Div-->
           <div class="col-lg-4 d-md-block d-none"></div>
           <!--End of Empty Div-->
            <div class="col-lg-4 col-12">
               <div class="link-end">
                  <a href="#" class="first-link">Help</a>
                  <div class="dropdown">
                     <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                       Action
                     </button>
                     <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                       <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
                     </div>
                   </div>
               </div>
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want the dropdown menu to be responsible. It only got irresponsible when I align both to inline. I want the drop-down menu to be aligned properly not to the left side of the screen. I want it responsive

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To test the grid structure, I removed the styles that added margin and padding to the elements. Then I updated the columns for responsive design; see the reference document for the grid system to be displayed differently in different browser sizes.

[image]

```css
.btn-search {
  background-color: #EEEFEE;
}

.fa-search {
  color: #8E8F8F;
}

.link-end {
  text-align: end;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: end;
  align-items: baseline;
}

.first-link {
 margin-right: 10px;
}

.customDropdownStyle{
  margin-right: 110px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/popper.js@1.16.1/dist/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script> 
    <script src="https://use.fontawesome.com/f1e10fbba5.js"></script> 
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="contact.css">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Print-Shop Contact</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="top-section">
      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control">
            <div class="input-group-append">
              <button class="btn btn-search" type="button">
                <i class="fa fa-search"></i>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4"></div>
        
        <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-4">
          <div class="link-end">
            <a href="#" class="first-link">Help</a>
            
            <div class="dropdown customDropdownStyle">
              <button class="btn btn-secondary dropdown-toggle" type="button" id="dropdownMenuButton" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false"> Action </button>
              <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenuButton">
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a>
                <a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

---

###### References

- [Grid system](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/)

Comment: bro it is not working

Comment: I updated; there was a missing js reference.

Comment: Dropdown is overflowing from the page because it takes up a lot of space; so you need to extend the last container.

Comment: nope, it still moves the left side of the screen you can. Ok let me increase space

Comment: @shawaizminhas I added right margin to dropdown; Check the `customDropdownStyle` style. This time I think I did what you thought.

Comment: You did it, bro. Can you do a favour more in small screen the menu open in upper direction how to open this in downward

Comment: I did not understand what you said.

Comment: On the small screen, the dropdown menu (link) move upward check this on the small screen. I want it work small as in large screen mean in dropdown way

Comment: Everything is working normally in my local. I think this is undefined behavior. You may need to research the source.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240730/discussion-between-shawaiz-minhas-and-sercan).

Answer (score 0):

just update the css of this class `.link-end` add this line in the css     `align-items: flex-end;`

check the link here of updated code. [updated code](https://codepen.io/mirza_irtiza/pen/LYzmoYM)

Comment: nope bro still it moves left outside of screen

Comment: items are not aligned in the horizontal plane: https://i.stack.imgur.com/zL10U.png

Comment: but I want the dropdown menu to center not left of screen

Comment: bro I just updated the code. the buttons are now centralized align in responsive